# Remove one to many relationship with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one to many relationship

In my Task controller

```
public function todo()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Todo');
}
```

In my Todo controller

```
public function tasks()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Adding the relationship with the following code

```
$todo = new Todo
$todo->save();
$task = new Task
$todo->tasks()->save($task);
$task->save();
```

but i want to delete it later not the object just the relationship

any ideas

Answer (score 10):

In [this chapter of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models):

```
When removing a belongsTo relationship, you may use the dissociate method. 
This method will reset the foreign key as well as the relation on the child model:

$user->account()->dissociate();
$user->save();
```

So in your case,

```
$task->todo()->dissociate();
$task->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a normal schema, you'll have a `todo_id` column on your `tasks` table. Unset it for the record you want to detach.

```
$task->todo_id = null;
$task->save();
```